# laravel with jquery ajax populate select option with value

Tags: ajax, laravel

I have two questions

(
**1.** how to automatically select the current level_id and populate it to the select box

**2.** how do i can i fix this issue in modal when closing and re-open another modal the select option  keeps on adding the previous data)

**controller:**

```
 $stream = Stream::with('level')->findOrFail($uuid);
        $levels =Level::all();
        return response()->json(['stream'=>$stream,'levels'=>$levels,'status'=>true]);
```

**Ajax Jquery**

```
 jQuery('body').on('click', '.open-modal', function() {
        var stream_id = $(this).val();
        $.get('streams/' + stream_id + '/edit', function(data) {
            if (data.status == true) {
                $.each(data.levels, function(i, level) {
                    $('#sel_level').append($('<option>', {
                        value: level.id,
                        text: level.name
                    }));
                });
            }
            jQuery('#stream_id').val(data.stream.id);
            jQuery('#stream_name').val(data.stream.name);
            jQuery('#stream_code').val(data.stream.code);
            jQuery('#btn-save').val("update");
            jQuery('#streamEditorModal').modal('show');

        })

    });
```

**Question 2 image**
[image]

**Json response;**

```
levels: Array(2)
0: {id: 3, name: "Level 1", code: "LVL1", uuid: "U7iHTp2pyM843HwfJ3CEB66rrD2vKAJvBHcrRYSGgXvmSaWh6IN3dGu1vZl29CwKTlULAdzduTglYyRFmn6MdY9S2xLhWZkvhSz0", created_at: "2020-06-25T07:59:14.000000Z", …}
1: {id: 4, name: "Level 2", code: "LVL2", uuid: "HZMe0wtyHfJrInriw4bA1ujOyZwZ7SkrSt37ZK2hCOHqSyki2b1Ysx2GBs8AU7oDemub2KmDNHBBiQhVaTkxyDAv7EXnUZ7O6DDi", created_at: "2020-06-25T07:59:25.000000Z", …}
length: 2
__proto__: Array(0)
status: true
stream:
code: "CLB3"
created_at: "2020-06-25T06:28:12.000000Z"
id: 17
level: {id: 3, name: "Level 1", code: "LVL1", uuid: "U7iHTp2pyM843HwfJ3CEB66rrD2vKAJvBHcrRYSGgXvmSaWh6IN3dGu1vZl29CwKTlULAdzduTglYyRFmn6MdY9S2xLhWZkvhSz0", created_at: "2020-06-25T07:59:14.000000Z", …}
level_id: 3
name: "Class B"
updated_at: "2020-07-02T07:58:39.000000Z"
uuid: "cq44VJZSOjRk4bB3S1Oz7UGX4yTPVHLnMvKYX648yVz1etQjj7obvzNuI9ExYfMCivMkuwNSSokmy82xvFPEAalhpmM2kFIhNPra"
_
```

Comment: I don't understand the first question but for the second one to stop repeating the options every time you open the modal, just add `$('#sel_level').html('')` before the `$.each` loop

Comment: question one auto populate the current level which refers to stream.level_id

Comment: Where is the current level ? do you mean the text field with the label 'Level' once you select a level value from the select box ?

Comment: stream:
code: "CL1A"
created_at: "2020-06-25T06:02:48.000000Z"
id: 12
level: null
level_id: null <<this the current level_id is nullable and it is related to levels: Array(2)
0: {id: as forenkey

Comment: each stream has level and using the level_id as foreign key now select box will auto target the current level_id of stream then if null it will show please select level

Comment: Ok try this, in the `$.each` loop after the `text` property add this property `selected: level.id === data.level_id`
this should automatically select the level if the level_id match the level id

Comment: how do i handle null if leve_id is null

Comment: if the value is null, no levels would be selected.

Comment: its not working .  value: level.id,
                        text: level.name,
                        selected: level.id === data.level_id,

Comment: it should work if the level.id = the value_id and since you have the levels[0].id = 3 and the  data.level_id = 3 then it should work
try using == instead of ===, so it would be like this
`selected: data.value_id == level.id`

Comment: nice work now the issue was data.level_id console result was undefined; correct is  data.stream.level_id  hehe thank you.. can u post the answers so i can accept it . thank you so much.:-)

Comment: Oh sorry about that, i didn't notice the level_id was under stream.
i will submit an answer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how to automatically select the current level_id and populate it to the select box
> To fix this issue you will need to reset the `select` element html content before appending new children like so:
> before the jQuery `$.each loop` just add

```
$('#sel_level').html('');
```

> how do i can i fix this issue in modal when closing and re-open another modal the select option keeps on adding the previous data)

To automatically select the current level you can check if the `stream.level_id` in the response match the current level id inside the loop like so:

```
$.each(data.levels, function(i, level) {
    $('#sel_level').append($('<option>', {
        value: level.id,
        text: level.name,
        selected: level.id == data.stream.level_id
     }));
});
```

**Fina code**

```
jQuery('body').on('click', '.open-modal', function() {
    var stream_id = $(this).val();
    $.get('streams/' + stream_id + '/edit', function(data) {
        if (data.status == true) {
            $('#sel_level').html('');
            $.each(data.levels, function(i, level) {
                $('#sel_level').append($('<option>', {
                    value: level.id,
                    text: level.name,
                    selected: level.id == data.stream.level_id
                }));
            });
        }
        jQuery('#stream_id').val(data.stream.id);
        jQuery('#stream_name').val(data.stream.name);
        jQuery('#stream_code').val(data.stream.code);
        jQuery('#btn-save').val("update");
        jQuery('#streamEditorModal').modal('show');

    })

});
```